# CSS centering multiple images/elements

Tags: css, image, center

I would like to center the following 2 buttons side by side rather than underneath one another. Here is [an example of how it is looking at the moment on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ws9r/1/)

Could you advise me the best way to handle this? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Define **display:inline-block** to your `anchor tags` & define **text-align:center** to it's `parent`. Write like this:

```
a.button {
     display:inline-block;
     *display:inline;/* For IE7 */
     *zoom:1;/*For IE7*/
     padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
     width:50px;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     text-align: center;
     color: #636363;
     text-decoration: none;
     border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
     border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
     border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
     border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.parent{
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <a class="button">Test</a>
    <a class="button">Test</a>
</div>
```

Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/2ws9r/11/

Answer (score 1):

add a container with fixed width and margin 0 auto;

http://jsfiddle.net/2ws9r/13/

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ws9r/10/)

```
<div>
  <a class="button">Test</a>
  <a class="button">Test</a>
</div>

div{ text-align: center; }
a.button {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
     width:50px;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     text-align: center;
     color: #636363;
     text-decoration: none;
     border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
     border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
     border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
     border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
}

a.button:hover  {
     color: #179FD9;
}
```

Comment: Removing the display:block; moves them to the left and doesn't center them. example http://jsfiddle.net/2ws9r/5/

Comment: or make it display:inlineblock;

Comment: Thanks Dipaks. Just tried this and it is working fine. Stupidly didn't think of wrapping it in a div and centering that!